# No me despliega las opciones de checkbox para la actualización de los registros

Tags: html5, bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Al tratar de actualizar el registro no me despliega las opciones de las categorias de los checkbox. En la imagen a continuación muestra y funciona correctamente cuado voy a adicionar un registro, las categorias son otra tabla diferente a la de productos y ambas tablas tienen una relacioón de muchos a muchos atraves de una tabla intermedia:

[image: Edición del registro]

[image: Ingreso del registro]

---

### Modelo products

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: products
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string
#  price      :decimal(12, 2)
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :has_categories
    has_many :categories, through: :has_categories

    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :price, presence: true

    after_create :save_categories

  #Custom setter
    def categories=(value)
        @categories = value
    end

    private

    def save_categories
    @categories.each do |category_id|
            HasCategory.create(category_id: category_id, product_id: self.id) #self es la instancia actual de product
        end
    end

end
```

---

### Modelo category

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: categories
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Category < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, presence: true

    has_many :has_categories
    has_many :products, through: :has_categories
end
```

---

### Modelo has_category (tabla intermedia para las relaciones muchos a muchos)

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: has_categories
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  product_id  :integer
#  category_id :integer
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#

class HasCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :category
end
```

---

### partial _form para la creación y actualización de registros de productos

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
      <h1><%= form_title %></h1>

      <% if @product.errors.any? %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <ul>
          <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
           <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <%= form_for @product do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control input-lg", placeholder: "Nombre del producto"%>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.number_field :price, class: 'text_field', step: 0.01, class: "form-control input-lg", placeholder: "Precio del producto" %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <% unless @categories.nil? %>
            <% @categories.each do |category| %>
               <div class="field">
                 <%= check_box_tag "category_ids[]", category.id %> <%= category.name %>
               </div>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <div>
          <%= f.submit form_title, class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### controlador ProductsController

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    @product.categories = category_params
     if @product.save
          redirect_to products_path, notice: 'El producto fue publicado exitosamente'
     else
      render :new
      end
    end

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @product.update(product_params)
      redirect_to products_path, notice: "El producto ha sido modificado con éxito"
   else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    product.destroy

    redirect_to products_path, notice: "El producto fue eliminado con éxito"
  end

  private
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price)
    end

    def category_params
      params.require(:category_ids)
    end

    def find_product
            @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

Comment: No te aparece porque en la acción edit no estas enviando la variable @categories hacia la vista. no te da ningún error porque tu validas que si la variable no sea nil.

Comment: Como debría hacer esa definición, ya que según las relaciones es HasCategory quien se debe actualizar.

Comment: Al agregar @categories = Category.all a la acción edit ya me despliega todas las categorias pero no muestra las que se le han asignado al artículo, necesito ver cuales son las del artículo para modificarlas en caso de que lo requiera.

Answer (score 0):

No tienes asignada la variable @categories en tu ProductsController.
El codigo dentro de tu products_controller.rb debe ser:

```
def edit
   @categories = @product.categories
end
```

Si el producto no tiene asignadas categorías entonces el drop down no se mostrara en la vista porque tienes un `unless @categories.nil?`

Comment: Aún con la modificación propuesta por usted no muestra los otros checkbox en el edit, igual probé quitando la validación del formulario para que solo mostrará las categorías asignadas y ni asi funciona :(

Comment: Ese producto tiene categorias ?  intenta entrar a la consola de rails y ver  un producto con categorías. Con el comando: rails console entras en la consola ahora puedes hacer product = Product.take despues intenta con product.categories

Comment: Si, los productos tienen las categorías asociadas.

Answer (score 0):

**Para solucionar el problema debí reemplazar el siguiente bloque de la vista partial form **

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control input-lg",  placeholder: "Nombre del producto"%>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.number_field :price, class: 'text_field', step: 0.01, class: "form-control input-lg", placeholder: "Precio del producto" %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <% unless @categories.nil? %>
            <% @categories.each do |category| %>
               <div class="field">
                 <%= check_box_tag "category_ids[]", category.id %> <%=    category.name %>
               </div>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
       <div>
          <%= f.submit form_title, class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

**Por el este bloque**

```
           <div class="form-group">
             <%= f.number_field :price, class: 'text_field', step: 0.01, class: "form-control input-lg", placeholder: "Precio del producto" %>
           </div>
           <div class="field">
                  <div class="field">
                    <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true}) do |ds| %>
                           <%= ds.label(class:"container") do %>
                             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= ds.check_box %>
                             <%= ds.object.name %>
                              <span class="chekmark"></span>
                           <% end %>
                    <% end %>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div>
```

<%= f.submit form_title, class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" %>

**Y modificar el controlador ProductsController**

```
def edit
     @all_categories = Category.all
     @categories = find_categories
     @categories = @product.categories
end

def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price, category_ids:[])
end
```